# Dynamic population of dropdown based on another dropdown in xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am in need of getting state and corresponding cities from selected country, in Xamarin.Android (need not in Xamarin.Forms)

I populate the countries in Spinner control as shown below

```
Spinner spinnerMailingCountry;
int[] countryId = new int[] { 0, 58, 98, 105, 86 };
String[] countryName = { "Select", "England", "Germany", "India"};
ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter;
String countryIdByPosition;
int selectedPosition;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ...
spinnerMailingCountry = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerMailingCountry);

SetupCountrySpinner();
}
void SetupCountrySpinner()
        {
            countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, countryName);
            countryAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);

            spinnerMailingCountry.Adapter = countryAdapter;
            spinnerMailingCountry.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CountrySpinner_ItemSelected);
        }

private void CountrySpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            var spinner = (Spinner)sender;
            selectedPosition = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
            countryIdByPosition = countryId[selectedPosition].ToString();
        }
```

Now once a country is selected, I need to populate list of corresponding state in spinner. This flow is also for city too. How can I achieve this?

NOTE: State and city lists are getting from my database through API call.

Comment: just do the same setup you have for SetupCountrySpinner, but only call it after CountrySpinner_ItemSelected is fired

Comment: Disable the State and City dropdown until the user selects a country, then enable state once he adds the country. Once he selects the state, enable the city. Usually, that is how it's maintained. Use `ArrayAdapter` for this. Basically keep it the same as you have for country

Comment: Hey bro ,does this problem has been solved ?

Answer (score 1):

> Now once a country is selected, I need to populate list of corresponding state in spinner. This flow is also for city too. How can I achieve this?

When `CountrySpinner_ItemSelected` be invoked, you can set `ArrayAdapter` for **State**.And  when State be selected, you can set `ArrayAdapter` for **City**.

**axml:**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCountry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerState"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />
```

**Activity.cs** : Adding test data( *stateName / cityName *)

```
Spinner spinnerMailingCountry;
Spinner spinnerMailingState;
Spinner spinnerMailingCity;
int[] countryId = new int[] { 0, 58, 98, 105, 86 };
String[] countryName = { "Select", "England", "Germany", "India" };
String[] stateName = { "Select", "EnglandStateOne", "EnglandStateTwo", "EnglandStateThree" };
String[] cityName = { "Select", "EnglandCityOne", "EnglandCityTwo", "EnglandCityThree" };
ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter;
ArrayAdapter<String> cityAdapter;
String countryIdByPosition;
int selectedPosition;
```

**OnCreate** Method:

```
spinnerMailingCountry = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerCountry);
spinnerMailingState = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerState);
spinnerMailingState.Enabled = false;
spinnerMailingCity = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerCity);
spinnerMailingCity.Enabled = false;

countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, countryName);
spinnerMailingCountry.Adapter = countryAdapter;

spinnerMailingCountry.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CountrySpinner_ItemSelected);
spinnerMailingState.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(StateSpinner_ItemSelected);
spinnerMailingCity.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CitySpinner_ItemSelected);
```

**CountrySpinner_ItemSelected** : Display state according to country.

```
private void CountrySpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    var spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    selectedPosition = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
    countryIdByPosition = countryId[selectedPosition].ToString();
    if(selectedPosition != 0) {
        stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stateName);
        //stateAdapter's data can get from your databse API with countryIdByPosition 

        spinnerMailingState.Enabled = true;
        spinnerMailingState.Adapter = stateAdapter;

    }
    else
    {
        spinnerMailingState.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

**StateSpinner_ItemSelected:** Display city according to state.

```
private void StateSpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    var spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    selectedPosition = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
    cityAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, cityName);
    if (selectedPosition != 0)
    {
        spinnerMailingCity.Enabled = true;
        spinnerMailingCity.Adapter = cityAdapter;

        //cityAdapter' data can get from your databse API with selectedPosition 
        Console.WriteLine("-------------" + stateName[selectedPosition].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        spinnerMailingCity.Enabled = false;
    }

}
```

**CitySpinner_ItemSelected:** Show the city you want.

```
private void CitySpinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    var spinner = (Spinner)sender;
    selectedPosition = spinner.SelectedItemPosition;
    Console.WriteLine("-------------" + cityName[selectedPosition].ToString());

}
```

When **OnDestroy** , unregister ItemSelected event:

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    base.OnDestroy();
    spinnerMailingCountry.ItemSelected -= new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CountrySpinner_ItemSelected);
    spinnerMailingState.ItemSelected -= new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(StateSpinner_ItemSelected);
    spinnerMailingCity.ItemSelected -= new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CitySpinner_ItemSelected);
}
```

Comment: I tried the above code. Everything is working fine except ItemSelected event called multiple times. For the first time, it has no problem. But whenever country is selected from second time onwards, ItemSelected event of state triggers 2 times, then 3 times and go on. This case is for city also. I think ItemSelected event is registered every time

Comment: @ThamaraiT Yeah, this needs improvement. I will update answer. :)

Comment: @ThamaraiT Having updated answer, if be helpful ,thanks for marking it in advance.*.^

Comment: I did this in SetupCountrySpinner() itself.      'spinnerMailingCountry.ItemSelected -= new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CountrySpinner_ItemSelected);'      'spinnerMailingCountry.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CountrySpinner_ItemSelected);'

Comment: @ThamaraiT Your solution is very good.Glad you solved it ! :)